# I can not center the div content

Tags: css, position, centering

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7UwD2/

I've tried everything I found on the internet - setting:

`margin: 0px auto;` with `width`, but it doesn't work.

Only if I'll add an attribute: `text-align: center;` to the `head-title` class it does center - but only the text, image is still on the left position.

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove the `float` from the image,
- use `text-align: center` on the outer DIV,
- use a SPAN instead of the inner DIV,
- apply `vertical-align: middle` to the image and SPAN

HTML:

```
<div class="head-title">
    <img class="list-icon" src="...">
    <span>Menu</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.head-title {
    width: 150px;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 5px;        
    text-align: center;
}

.head-title > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.list-icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7UwD2/6/

Comment: Nice skill mate! Works like a charm. :) Thank you.